# using the group Z4 to shorten code

Tags: java

is it possible to have a variable set in the group of Z4. So that if i had the following code

```
"int" x = 3;
x = x + 1;
```

the value of x would be 0. I know I can use mod 4 but I was wondering if you can change "int" to make it mod 4

Comment: What is `"Z4"`? Please clarify.

Comment: Do you mean the mathematical cyclic group? You could create an object for this you know. One that has an increment method.

Comment: Z4 is the set {0,1,2,3}. any integer has a value in it. which is its remainder when divided by 4

Comment: You can't do it. But what you can do, is defer the `mod 4` all the way till the end after you've done all the operations on it that you wanted to do (and be sure to write it as `& 3` to avoid difficulty with negative numbers). That is valid because any normal overflow is also modulo a power of two.

Comment: Hovercraft Full Of Eels  how would I do that. that was the question I was trying to ask

Comment: If you use your own class, sure, you could do that (it's trivial, even). But you wouldn't be able to write + and * and so on any more - there's no operator overloading in Java.

Comment: @user3328784: simply give your class add/subtract/increment/decrement methods, and in those methods perform the proper mod operations before setting the field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I know I can use mod 4 but I was wondering if you can change "int" to make it mod 4.

It is not possible in Java.

(In fact, I cannot think of *any* mainstream programming language where you can do this.  In Ada and one or two other languages you can define types that are subranges of an integer type, but I don't recall one where you could define a range type with modular arithmetic.)

---

Here are some alternatives:

- Define a class with static helper methods that perform arithmetic on Z4 values stored as `int`.
- Define a class whose values represent Z4 values with a range of arithmetic methods.
- Just do the arithmetic using regular `int` and integer operators, and convert to Z4 at the appropriate time by masking out all but the 2 bottom bits.

Comment: One could do it in C++ via operator overloading.

Comment: @Conrad - but that is not a built-in type constructor, and that's what I'm talking about.